# Is it possible to implement Google-style enterprise-wide authentication using WSO2IS?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, google-account, wso2-identity-server

I am looking into a solution that provides both authentication and authorization for several different service providers while using WSO2 Identity Server as the Identity Provider.

Similar to Google, I have all these applications internally (ie. gmail, drive, etc). I want to have a login that's central which can take authentication requests from any service provider, like how Google has one page that handles every login: https://accounts.google.com .

Leveraging WSO2 IS's platform, would a solution similar to this be possible? If so, what approach do I have to take to implement this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 Identity Server, you can configure several services providers. For the SP configuration please refer to [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider).

If you want to enable single sign-on(SSO) please refer to [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Single+Sign-On). When enabling SSO you can use a protocol that you prefer. WSO2 IS supports SAML, OAuth/OpenID connect and etc.